# Reader-writer semaphores for unrelated processes

Tags: synchronization, ipc, semaphore

For my application, I need an [rw_semaphore](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch09lev1sec5). Since [readers-writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) is not totally trivial, and the work seems to have been done and debugged already, I'd like to use linux `rwsem` functionality.

POSIX semaphores are opened with a name that is a string starting with a forward slash. This makes it easy to connect two unrelated processes. However, the `rwsem` module does not seem to provide such a way to access the same semaphore from unrelated processes.

`DECLARE_RWSEM` from `rwsem.h` takes one parameter, and that is the identifier of the `struct rw_semaphore` being declared.

How do I use a `rw_semaphore` in two or more unrelated processes?

Answer (score 0):

rw_semaphores are used for thread synchronisation within a process. They are not for Inter-Process Communication.

For the you need regular semaphores. See http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-5.html